# vue binding value based on media query

Tags: css, vue.js

```
carousel-3d(:display="3", :width="150", :height="150")
```

I want to set the attribute bindings based on a media query

e.g.

display should become 5 when screen width > 960px

Comment: https://github.com/AlexandreBonaventure/vue-mq

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could try binding the **display** value to a component property:

```
<carousel-3d :display="display">
```

...and then update that property on window resize:

```
...

data() {
  return {
    display: 3
  }
},

methods: {
  onResize() {
    if (window.innerWidth > 960) {
      this.display = 5
    } else {
      this.display = 3
    }
  }
},

created() {
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize)
},

beforeDestroy() {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onResize)
},

...
```

Comment: Sure. That's a way. But using javascript for what should be done with CSS, isn't it bad for performance? Have you stumbled across better something working with Vuejs as I had the same question.

Comment: Also, you are adding event on DOM directly. Vue or React works on concept of Virtual DOM.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled to find any solutions with Vuejs alone myself or if at all that are there, are already too complex. Involves a lot of unnecessary work where things can be done neatly and in CSS.

That solution is `styled components` or for a matter of fact any `CSS in JS` solutions to handle such things with ease.

For example in styled components your styles are written inside ES6 template literal.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import breakpoint from '../utils/breakpoint.js';

const YourStyledComponent = styled.div`
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    @media (min-width: ${breakpoint.SM}px) {
        // Your media styles
    }
`;
```

Then inside your Vue component use it as a normal component. You can pass it props as well. Do read more about it - [Vue-styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/vue-styled-components).

Doing this way you are using just CSS for styling everything. It's a must for front-end development considering the performance. I think it's a long time since we stopped adding eventListeners to Javascript related to styling or handling layout.