# How to change background image on mobile view?

Tags: css, vue.js

I need to change the background image in mobile and desktop view. I used below code to display background image.

```
<img class="slider_Style" :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + offer.slider_image + ')', backgroundPosition: '50% 50%' }" />
```

How to change the code for mobile view using conditions.

Comment: You can use media queries for it: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: @ShivamArora Media queries does not catch my background image variable.

Comment: @Saji it may help you :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47143204/vue-binding-value-based-on-media-query

Comment: @BjørnNyborg You are correct. Thank you

Comment: @Saji No problem. Moved my comment to an answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An img tag with a background-image, isn't this a bit wierd syntax? If i was you i would just use normal src for the img tag, and then have 2 different element, that you show/hide depending on screensize. (Javascript window.width or css media-queries)